# NullReferenceException was unhandled and I don't know why?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, nullreferenceexception

I'm creating a WPF C# application that has a datagrid hooked up to a SQL Server database. The user has the option of editing data in the datagrid by highlighting a row and clicking an edit button which then populates several textboxes with the data from the highlighted row. At this point, the user can then edit the data, click save and the datagrid reflects the changes. Until recently that feature was working fine. However, I was asked to add a feature that displays a highlighted row of data somewhere else on the screen (as looking at a datagrid for too long can become tiresome). So when a user clicks on a row a series of textblocks to the right of the datagrid change to show the data of the highlighted row in an easier to view format. That feature also works fine. The issue I'm having now, is that when a row is highlighted and automatically displays the data in the textblocks, if the user also tries to edit that row, the application crashes. The data displays just fine in the textboxes after the user clicks edit (while simultaneously displaying the same highlighted row in the textblocks); it's just when save is clicked that I run into an issue.

Debugging the program shows that everything is running smoothly. However after clicking save, the debugger jumps back up to my myGridSelectionChanged event and say's "NullReferenceException was unhandled -- Object reference not set to instance of an object" When I reload the program however, the datagrid reflects the changes that I tried to make before the application crashed. I'm assuming that means that the issue doesn't have to do with actually editing the database, rather the problem is with the textblocks not being able to reflect those edits. Below is some of my code:

Here is the code for the save button:

```
     private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var stqmDC = new SqtmLinqDataContext();

        var selectedRow = EditGrid.GetSelectedRow(myGrid);
        var ID = EditGrid.GetCell(myGrid, selectedRow, 0);
        string selectedID = ((TextBlock)ID.Content).Text;
        int convertedID = Convert.ToInt32(selectedID);

        int newQuantity = int.Parse(quantityTxt.Text);

        var query = from info in stqmDC.General_Infos
                    where info.Quote_ID == convertedID
                    select info;

        foreach (General_Info info in query)
        {
            info.Customer_Name = customerNameTxt.Text;
            info.OEM_Name = oemNameTxt.Text;
            info.Qty = newQuantity;
            info.Quote_Num = quoteNumberTxt.Text;
            info.Fab_Drawing_Num = fabDrawingNumTxt.Text;
            info.Rfq_Num = rfqNumberTxt.Text;
            info.Rev_Num = revNumberTxt.Text;
        }

        try
        {
            stqmDC.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        var mainTable = from generalInfo in stqmDC.GetTable<General_Info>()
                        select new
                        {
                            generalInfo.Quote_ID,
                            generalInfo.Open_Quote,
                            generalInfo.Customer_Name,
                            generalInfo.OEM_Name,
                            generalInfo.Qty,
                            generalInfo.Quote_Num,
                            generalInfo.Fab_Drawing_Num,
                            generalInfo.Rfq_Num,
                            generalInfo.Rev_Num
                        };



        myGrid.ItemsSource = mainTable;

        leftSP.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        rightSP.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        cancelBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        submitBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        saveBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        sendBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    }
```

And the code for displaying the highlighted row in textblocks:

```
    private void myGridSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rowSelection = EditGrid.GetSelectedRow(myGrid);

        var quoteID = EditGrid.GetCell(myGrid, rowSelection, 0);
        string quoteIDEdit = ((TextBlock)quoteID.Content).Text;
        QuoteIDtxtblk.Text = quoteIDEdit;

        var date = EditGrid.GetCell(myGrid, rowSelection, 1);
        string dateEdit = ((TextBlock)date.Content).Text;
        Datetxtblk.Text = dateEdit;

        var custName = EditGrid.GetCell(myGrid, rowSelection, 2);
        string custNameEdit = ((TextBlock)custName.Content).Text;
        CustomerNametxtblk.Text = custNameEdit;

        var OemName = EditGrid.GetCell(myGrid, rowSelection, 3);
        string OemNameEdit = ((TextBlock)OemName.Content).Text;
        OemNametxtblk.Text = OemNameEdit;

        var Quantity = EditGrid.GetCell(myGrid, rowSelection, 4);
        string QuantityEdit = ((TextBlock)Quantity.Content).Text;
        Quantitytxtblk.Text = QuantityEdit;

        var quoteNum = EditGrid.GetCell(myGrid, rowSelection, 5);
        string quoteNumEdit = ((TextBlock)quoteNum.Content).Text;
        QuoteNumbertxtblk.Text = quoteNumEdit;

        var fabDrawing = EditGrid.GetCell(myGrid, rowSelection, 6);
        string fabDrawingEdit = ((TextBlock)fabDrawing.Content).Text;
        FabDrawingNumbertxtblk.Text = fabDrawingEdit;

        var rfqNum = EditGrid.GetCell(myGrid, rowSelection, 7);
        string rfqNumEdit = ((TextBlock)rfqNum.Content).Text;
        RfqNumbertxtblk.Text = rfqNumEdit;

        var revNum = EditGrid.GetCell(myGrid, rowSelection, 8);
        string revNumEdit = ((TextBlock)revNum.Content).Text;
        RevNumbertxtblk.Text = revNumEdit;

    }
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: Do you know on which line the exception is occurring?

Comment: Try changing MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); to MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());  That should show the stack trace and might narrow it down

Comment: JLRishe, the exception occurs in myGridSelectionChanged() on the second line: varQuoteID = EditGrid.GetCell(myGrid, rowSelection, 0);

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly would you think it's handled?

To handle exceptions that cause app crashes you need to exception-proof every "entry point", defined as every spot in your app where unmanaged code can call in or a the code starts running on a different thread.

This includes button click handlers. Add a try/catch in your button handler and show some UI message that an error happened and write a log message or at least a 'Debug.WriteLine(exceptionObjectHere);' so you can see where did the exception come from

Comment: The error doesn't appear in my button handler--the save button appears to still be working properly, because when I reload the application, the edits that I make appear in the datagrid. The exception occurs in myGridSelectionChanged on the second line. When I surround that code with a try/catch block, I get the error, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @wrigley06 which line gives you the null exception?

Comment: @wrigley06 The bigger question is why do you try to manually force data out of the datagrid if you can just bind your other controls' content to the selected item of the grid and spare yourself the entire myGridSelectionChanged method

Answer (score 0):

You change `ItemsSource` of a `DataGrid` in `saveBtn_Click` which means that your selection will disapear and `SelectionChanged` will be fired.

So you need to handle this case (`myGrid.SelectedItem == null`) somewhere, and just do nothing (return) if so.